# Como consumir un api para obtener un get token acces con oauth 2.0 grant type client credentials con C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

estoy tratando de consumir un api rest con oauth 2.0 desde C# con net core, ya pude probar el api desde el postman pero el codigo que me genera no me sirve para llamar al api y generar el token para posteriormente poder acceder a los otros metodos.

en el postman tengo configurado el api de la siguiente manera

[image: Configuracion del postman]

y cuando realizo el llamado me genera mi token de la siguiente manera:

[image: Respuesta del api]

en mi aplicación tengo el siguiente código para llamar y generar el token pero cuando hago el llamado me da un error con estatus 401 diciendo que no estoy autorizado he probado distintas manera pero con ninguna obtengo la respuesta deseada adjunto el codigo que utilizo:

```
            var client = new RestClient("yourlinkgettoken");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer <access_token>");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
            "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=api&client_secret=1234", ParameterType.RequestBody);            
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: `request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<access_token>");` te falta agregar el token de esa forma

Comment: soy todavia un principiante con que using referencia ese clases DefaultRequestHeaders

Answer (score 0):

perdon, veo que estas usando restsharp, yo he usando el token de esta manera

```
  var client = new RestClient("yourUrl") { Timeout = -1,};
  var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {<access_token>}");
```

otra manera es usando AddParameter

```
  request.AddParameter("Authorization",string.Format("Bearer " + "<access_token>"),ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

Comment: aun colocando el bearer access_token como parametro en el header el api me sigue respondiendo Error 401--Unauthorized

Comment: Estoy seguro que me falta algo en la configuracion o algun parametro por enviar pero no logro detectar que es!

Comment: @linkfelipe de casualidad podras compartir la api y el token para ayudarte de una mejor manera, haciendo pruebas desde mi maquina?

Answer (score 0):

En tu ejemplo al obtener el token no deberías enviar el encabezado de autorización (Header de authorization)

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer <access_token>");
```

Ya que este encabezado es cuando ya tienes el token y quieres realizar requests autenticadas al servidor.

Veo que estas utilizando el [componente nuget RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/), entonces arme un ejemplo para que lo puedas ver (o descargar) y tienes un demo y test

- [01-auth2-client-with-RestSharp](https://github.com/fernandezja/dotnet-oauth2-client/tree/main/01-auth2-client-with-RestSharp), lo deje en este repo [dotnet-oauth2-client](https://github.com/fernandezja/dotnet-oauth2-client)

Aquí dejo el código de esta parte de obtener token

```
public async Task<Token> GetTokenAsync(string url, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {

        var client = new RestClient(url);

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                $"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}",
                ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Token>(response.Content);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Enlaces que pueden servir de ayuda o guía

- [Componente nuget RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/)